# nth-child(odd) does not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, parent-child

I am trying to make some background color for every second element in html to be different color with **nth-child(odd)** but somehow it is not working as expected, because every child is given background color.

Here is working fiddle to see my problem, because it has a lot of HTMl to paste :)

https://jsfiddle.net/7xwgszwg/8/

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 accesories-box-main">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div style="background-image: url('content/images/accesories/accesories-hook.png');" class="col-md-12 accesories-box">
                                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                                        <p class="accesories-price" style="padding-top: 40px; padding-left: 20px;">

                                     420 
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 acccesories-description">
                                        <p>
                                            It also falls back to a solid color background if CSS gradients are not supported. It will work on Firefox 3.6+, Chrome, Safari, Opera 11.10+ and IE10+.
                                            PS: For my twitter friends, I had already written this when the robbers came and I was about to post it. I might have been really calm, but not as much as making CSS experiments the same day I was robbed and threatened by a gun
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 accesories-box-main">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div style="background-image: url('content/images/accesories/accesories-roof.png');" class="col-md-12 accesories-box">
                                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                                        <p class="accesories-price">
                                         420 
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 acccesories-description">
                                        <p>
                                            It also falls back to a solid color background if CSS gradients are not supported. It will work on Firefox 3.6+, Chrome, Safari, Opera 11.10+ and IE10+.
                                            PS: For my twitter friends, I had already written this when the robbers came and I was about to post it. I might have been really calm, but not as much as making CSS experiments the same day I was robbed and threatened by a gun
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 accesories-box-main">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div style="background-image: url('content/images/accesories/accesories-roof.png');" class="col-md-12 accesories-box">
                                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                                        <p class="accesories-price">
                                           420 
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 acccesories-description">
                                        <p>
                                            It also falls back to a solid color background if CSS gradients are not supported. It will work on Firefox 3.6+, Chrome, Safari, Opera 11.10+ and IE10+.
                                            PS: For my twitter friends, I had already written this when the robbers came and I was about to post it. I might have been really calm, but not as much as making CSS experiments the same day I was robbed and threatened by a gun
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the missing `h` in `nt-child` (*should be `nth-child`*) the problem is that the `.acccesories-description` elements are not siblings, and the `nth-child` differentiates between sibling elements.

You most likely want to apply the `nth-child` to the `.accesories-box-main` and then target the `.acccesories-description` for coloring

```
.accesories-box-main:nth-child(odd) .acccesories-description{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7xwgszwg/9/

Comment: I have updated the question without typos, please take a look?

Comment: @MiomirDancevic the answer i provide has fixed those as well so it stands as it is.

Comment: Yes this is solutiom, but why (odd) does not work with that selector?

Comment: Great txanks now i understand

Comment: @MiomirDancevic Sorry my previous comment was wrong. It is 1 based, but the element is the second child, the div with the background image before it is counted as the first child

Answer (score 0):

you have a typos, it's `nth-child()` you forgot the `h` : https://jsfiddle.net/7xwgszwg/4/

Comment: this works but your explanation isn't quite right, the class exists he just wasn't targeting it correctly (the elements weren't siblings so nth-child was the wrong choice here)

Comment: Ok good for you. Sorry I didn't found it with ctrl+f in your page.